# Make screenshots of Ti-calculator screen

Tags: serial-port, screenshot, calculator

I want to connect a [TI-84 Plus Calculator](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/productDetail/us_ti84p.html) to my PC and take screenshots of the calculator display. Under windows this is possible using the [TI-connect software](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/productDetail/us_ti_connect.html). However is there also a way to do this under linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [TiLP](http://lpg.ticalc.org/prj_tilp/). I've used it with my TI-84+ SE: it allows you to manage applications, programmes and variables, and IIRC it also has a "view screen" feature — either it has a screenshot function, or you can just use `import` or something else to grab a screenshot of TiLP showing the screen.